# Download Photo From Flickr URL

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, flickr

I need to download flickr images from given flickr URL , Is there any help or any good link .
Please help me out.
For more clarification, I have an URL http://www.flickr.com/photos/XYZ@ABC/ and it has few images . I need to download those images .

Thanks In advance
Abhishek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of the [Flickr API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/) is the place to start, and it probably has all the information you need.  That page links to a library for Objective-C clients, called (not surprisingly) [ObjectiveFlickr](https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr).